# Barra Fixa no topo

Tags: html, css, html5

Olá eu gostaria de por no topo da minha página uma barra da cor preta, mas não estou a conseguir fazer.

Alguém sabe como se faz??

Comment: O que você tentou?

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar [`position: fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) para esse fim:

```css
.barra {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="barra"></div>
```